# iOS function similar ti viewDidLoad()

Tags: ios, swift

I search a function (included in iOS or with external library) that is very similar to viewDidLoad(). The difference should be that the searched function will be used only when the App starts for the first time, that means when the user opened the App. ViewDidLoad() is used every time when the view was loaded. But the searched function xy() will only used when a view is loaded for the first time in the runtime.

**This is the normal version**

> User opened App, View 1 opens -> ViewDidLoad() of view 1 -> User opens
>   view 2 .... -> User goes back to View 1 -> ViewDidLoad() of View 1

**I search this**

> User opened App, View 1 opens -> ViewDidLoad() of view 1 and function
>   xy() -> User opens view 2 .... -> User goes back to View 1 ->
>   ViewDidLoad() of View 1 (this time not function xy() because the view
>   was already loaded in this runtime)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The AppDelegate is not suitable for your case?

Comment: `viewDidLoad` of View [Controller] 1 does not actually get called multiple times in a normal view controller hierarchy.

Comment: This behaviour is reliable, especially for all view controllers which are not the root view controller of the window.

Comment: Your question isn't valid because your summary of "the normal version" is not normal. `viewDidLoad` of view 1 will not be called when a user returns back to view 1 after dismissing view 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place code you need to run once in the `dispatch_once` block for **obj-c** and use `static var` for **swift**

**Obj-c:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        // code you place here will run once
    });
}
```

**Swift 3**

```
static var didInit = false

override func viewDidLoad() 
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if MyClass.didInit == false {
        MyClass.didInit = true
        // code you place here will run once
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
```